# How can I most efficiently execute this recursive/iterative CPU intensive android task?

Tags: java, android, performance, algorithm, recursion

Some Background Info: I have made a program that given an arraylist of letters, and an array of integers finds all the combinations of words that can exist inside this arraylist where the words length is one of the integers in the int array (wordSizes). 
i.e. given h, o, p, n, c, i, e, t, k and the integers 5 and 4, the solution would be:
phone tick.

My problem right now:
Inputs usually are about 25 characters and the output should usually return 5 word combinations.
I originally made this a console application for dekstop, and runtimes are generally less than 1 minute.
I decided to port it to android and runtimes reach over 35 minutes. I am quite a beginner and not sure about how to run a CPU intensive task on Android.

```
public void findWordsLimited(ArrayList<Character> letters) {

    for (String s1 : first2s) {
        for (String s2 : possibleSeconds) {

            boolean t = true;

            String s1s2 = s1.concat(s2);
            ArrayList<Character> tempLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(letters);
            for (int i = 0; i < s1s2.length(); i++) {
                if (tempLetters.contains(s1s2.charAt(i)))
                    tempLetters.remove(Character.valueOf(s1s2.charAt(i)));
                else
                    t = false;
            }

            if (t) {
                helperFindWordsL(tempLetters, s1 + " " + s2, 2);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void helperFindWordsL(ArrayList<Character> letters, String prefix , int index) {

    boolean r;

    if (letters.size() <= 1) {
        output += "Success : " + prefix + "\n";
        Log.i(TAG, prefix);
    }

    else if (index < wordSizes.size()){

        for (String s : lastCheck) {

            if (s.length() == wordSizes.get(index)) {

                ArrayList<Character> templetters = new ArrayList<Character>(letters);
                r = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                    if (templetters.contains(s.charAt(j)))
                        templetters.remove(Character.valueOf(s.charAt(j)));
                    else {
                        r = false;
                        templetters = new ArrayList<Character>(letters);
                    }
                }

                if (r)
                    helperFindWordsL(templetters, prefix + " " + s, index + 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am not too concerned about the algorithm, as this might be confusing because it is part of a bigger project to solve a word game puzzle.
A few questions:

How would I get a CPU intensive task like this finished fastest? 
Right now I call the method findWordsLimited() from my MainActivity. On my desktop app (where it says output += Success... in HelperFindWordsL) I would print all solutions to the console, but right now I have made it so that the method adds to and in the end returns a giant string (String output) back to the MainActivity, with all solutions and that String is put inside of a TextView. Is that an inefficient way to display the data? If so, could you please help explain a better way?

Should I be running this as a backgroud/foreground process or thread instead of just calling it from the MainActivity?

How can i get runtimes on my android that are currently 20x slower than my desktop faster?

Comment: It would appear that you are missing many opporunities to write an algorithm that is one or two orders of magnitude faster. But you haven't described one essential thing: how do you check whether a sequence of letters makes up a word? Also, the example should produce many more words besides "phone" and "tick"!

Comment: Before this runs, i have an array ready called lastCheck which has already iterated through a wordlist.txt. And yes, words other than phone and tick like nice and cope will work, but the way it works is that the combination of letters must map to a certain combination of words such that their sizes are the integers. a lot of times, multiple solutions do exist.

Comment: That wasn't really clear: the number of letters must be equal to the sum of the word lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace recursion with cycles, and use arrays instead of lists, to avoid inserts etc, direct access to array members is much faster. Pay main attention to the most inner loop which  uses `templetters.contains(s.charAt(j))`, optimization of this part of code will give main effect.

You may add `break;` after `t = false;`

`String s1s2 = s1.concat(s2);` - it's not good to create a new String object for such case - it makes unnecessary work for **GC**. I would replace it with 2 cycles through `s1` then `s2`

You could use 'letters' instead of `ArrayList<Character> tempLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(letters);`, just marking some items there as deleted. No need to create local clones.

Comment: thanks, these help with the java syntax but what i am more concerned about is the logistics of android. My desktop is able to run these quite quickly, but my android device does not. I was look ing to see how I would execute a CPU intensive process fastest on android, and should i continue to append results to a string, or do it another way, or switch to a process?

Comment: desktop CPU may be just more powerful. Desktop java may have a better JIT optimizations. I do not think you need to do anything in this regard, because your code may be easily optimized to get significant performance bust

Comment: @0xdeceab14 of course your Android device is not. Desktop and even laptop CPUs are much, much faster than anything in an Android device. You need to optimize your algorithm and then your code. We would probably need more details to talk about optimizing the algorithm, but Mixaz gave you some good suggestions for optimizing the code.

Comment: Ok, i optimized my code and it seems like just doing a few checks before the bulk of the recursive process in addition to optimizing the arraylist for loop (check, remove) reduced runtimes hundred-fold. Although it is still 10x faster on a computer, I was able to get managable runtimes usually under 2 minutes on my phone.